# Multiple xAxis line on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two different xaxis, one for the base chart and the other for the drilldown chart [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnbnbn/svfx1r34/).

[image]

Can someone explain to me why it creates an additional horizontal line and how I can remove it? The horizontal line does not seem to appear when I tried to reference the other axis `xAxis:1`

Comment: if you want to hide the the 2nd x-axis, you can add "visible": false to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use additional `xAxis` for a drilldown. The `categories` can be defined as point names (https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6ztaxush/) or you can use `update` or `setCategories method`.

If you really need to use both axis, you can set `visible` property to `false`:

```
xAxis: [{...},
    {
        type: 'category',
        visible: false
    }
],
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/91fv7jc2/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update